# OpenCV createCalibrateDebevec.process is giving me "dst is not a numpy array, neither a scalar"

Tags: python, c++, arrays, opencv, numpy

I'm currently trying to do some HDR processing with OpenCV's python wrapper.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread("1.jpg")
img2 = cv2.imread("2.jpg")
img3 = cv2.imread("3.jpg")

images = [img, img2, img3]
times = [-2, 0, 2]

response = np.zeros(256)
import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
calibrate = cv2.createCalibrateDebevec()
calibrate.process(images, response, times)

ipdb> calibrate.process(images, response, times)
*** TypeError: dst is not a numpy array, neither a scalar
```

It says that dst or 'response' in my code based on the position is not an numpy array but checking the type of 'response', it clearly says it is.

```
ipdb> type(response)
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

Comment: what version of cv2 are you using?

Comment: >>> import cv2
>>> cv2.__version__
'3.0.0'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use call

```
calibrate.process(images, times, response)
```

or

```
response = calibrate.process(images, times)
```

instead of

```
calibrate.process(images, response, times)
```

because python `CalibrateDebevec`'s `process` member signature is the following:

```
process(src, times[, dst]) -> dst
```

It can be simply determined with the following:

```
import inspect
print(inspect.getdoc(calibrate.process))
```

Comment: Ahh yes. For some reason I was convinced that the signature was process(src, dst, times). Thanks!

Comment: I am having an issue with the same HDR processing problem (although for different reasons). If you can, it would be nice if you could take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34433906/opencv-python-createmergedebevec-returns-an-array-of-inf